# Save selected content in tableview row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have custom tableview cell that have a content, I want to save it in new controller, when I called YouTube api I set max result 2, and it display in tableview only 2 row. And when I try to save in new controller it save 3 and one of them is duplicating. how can I save it? I already selected with sender.tag but it still return 3.

This is my code in tableview in VideoController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoId", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

    let video = videos[indexPath.row]
    cell.video = video
    cell.favoriteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.favoriteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleFavorite(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

and this is my **handleFavorite** function and add delegate in my VideoController

```
var delegate: SaveFavoriteDelegate?

@objc fileprivate func handleFavorite(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add to Favorite", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Favorite", style: .default) { (_) in
        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistenceContainer.viewContext

        let video = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Video", into: context)
            video.setValue(self.videos[sender.tag].videoTitle, forKey: "videoTitle")
            video.setValue(self.videos[sender.tag].videoId, forKey: "videoId")

            do {
                try context.save()

                self.delegate?.didAddVideoFavorite(for: video as! Video)
            } catch let saveErr {
                print("Failed to save into core data:", saveErr)
            }
        }

        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

I make a protocol to handle passing data into my new controller, this is my protocol code

```
protocol SaveFavoriteDelegate {
func didAddVideoFavorite(for video: Video)
}
extension FavoriteController: SaveFavoriteDelegate {

func didAddVideoFavorite(for video: Video) {
    videos.append(video)
    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: videos.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
}
```

Comment: Starting of your question is very confusing and unclear. What is 1, 2 and 3 ? CellNumber or something else ? Please be specific and clear in your requirement.

Comment: @iEngineer I mean when I called YouTube api I set max result 2, and it display in tableview only 2 row. And when I try to save in new controller it save 3 and one of them is duplicating.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Make sure your func handleFavorite is not called twice on single tap. Also your array videos in FavoriteController is empty before starting favourite process.

Comment: @iEngineer I already did, but it still not solve my problem. Thank you by the way